# why my relative Layout appear as a small square instead of occupying the entire width screen?

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, android-relativelayout

I use a relative layout with a textView in it.
At the runtime, the layout appear like a small square instead of occupying the entire width of the screen!?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/curriculum"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/HKCurriculum" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Could someone give me a hint on what I'm doing wrong please ?

Below the dialogFragment

```
class CvFragment : DialogFragment() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    var rootView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cv, container, false)
    var curriculum = rootView.findViewById<View>(R.id.curriculum)
```

//        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)

```
    curriculum.setOnClickListener(object :View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            dismiss()
        }
    })

    return rootView
}
```

}

and below an extract of the main activity

```
        val hkphoto: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.HK)
    hkphoto.setOnClickListener(this)
    override fun onClick(view: View?) {
    when (view!!.id) {
        R.id.gokyo_burger -> {
            val intent = Intent(this@GokyoActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        R.id.HK -> {
            val cv = supportFragmentManager
            val myFragment = CvFragment()
            myFragment.show(cv, "simple Fragment")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

blind bet: you have custom `android:configChanges`attr set in manifest for this `Activity` and also you are missing super call in below method in `Activity`

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    //super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig); <---- !!!
}
```

would be easier to guess with full `Activity`s code (as on screen there are some bronze views in bottom left corner)

Comment: I don't have a "...onConfigurationChanged..." in the Manifest. What do you mean with a "bronze views" in bottom left corner ? I just hided the screen below the TextView for the screenshot ?

Comment: I see some bronze fields just below bottom line of `TextView`, but still in phones frame. without code all is just guessing. XML is proper

Comment: well, copy and paste into edited question...?